# Use case design for collectors to fetch rpm, docker images, java packages

Tags: amazon-web-services, shell, kubernetes, rpm

I have to create a design to create a set of collectors that will go out to the internet sites, sftp-servers, docker hubs and/or buckets from the vendor(s) and pull in the packages (preferably anonymously or credentials if used must be handled properly) from these vendors into a location secure s3 bucket.

I have to do this using kubernetes and very new to this. Could you please suggest what are the various ways i can approach this problem.

Seeking suggestion on how to approach this.

Answer (score 0):

You are - more or less - describing [Pulp project](https://pulpproject.org/).